# Nesting custom Exception example

Tags: php, exception

I don't understand why this code:

```
class MyException extends Exception {};
try {
    try {
        throw new MyException;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "1:";
            throw $e;
        } catch (MyException $e) {
            echo "2:";
            throw $e;
        }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo get_class($e);
}
```

Returns: 1:MyException.

Isn't it supposed to catch the second one MyException and therefore return 2?

I thought with multiple exceptions it looks for the current try/catch first, but it looks like it catches the exception from the first try? or is it because MyException is empty and it uses Exception instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception here is a base class for your MyException class. Your $e variable has class MyException, so everything is right. If you make:

```
echo "1:";
var_dump($e);
throw $e;
```

you will see that $e is object(MyException). You haven't cast types, you just using [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

All your objects that have type Exception or it's subtypes will be caught in the 1-st block. Code will be executed in first by order block that can apply the exception.

Comment: But why it doesn't take the MyException catch so it returns echo "2"? Could you tell me the flow of the script?

Comment: @Diego because your 2-nd catch has same level, you can catch exception only 1 time and they will be catched in order. If 1-st catch can be applied, then it is applied and exits to outer block

Answer (score 1):

Catch blocks are processed in the order they appear. Your code for catching MyException will **never** be called, because all subclasses of Exception are caught in your first catch block.